# Can't control some areas in brick texture

Tags: shader-nodes

I can change colors, resize, and add more bricks in some areas, but not on these areas marked with red arrows. How do I control these? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Your setup is weird (and actually doesn't satisfy the rules of Blender Stack Exchange, as it is "too localized"). Instead of asking how to control these areas, maybe describe what kind of effect you want to achieve? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

As a debugging tip: all those areas are black, and also you use the black color in 7 (significant) places in your setup. Try to use a different color in each field, which should help you localizing which node is relevant to which area.